# FORECAST.ETS Function in Excel(2016) #N/A Error

Tags: excel, function, ms-office, forecasting, excel-2016

I try to do forecast.ets function about 2020, but I'm getting #N/A Error.

```
1790    3,929214
1800    5,308483
1810    7,239881
1820    9,638453
1840    17,069453
1850    23,191876
1860    31,443321
1870    39,818449
1880    50,189209
1890    62,979766
1900    76,212168
1910    92,228496
1920    106,021537
1930    123,202624
1940    132,164569
1950    151,325798
1960    179,323175
1970    203,302031
1980    226,542199
1990    248,718302
2000    281,424603
2010    308,745538
```

This are my numbers, and this is what i do:

```
A23: 2020
B23: =FORECAST.ETS(A23;B1:B22;A1:A22)
```

Answer (score 0):

B23 formula is incorrect.  It should have been:

```
=FORECAST.ETS(A23,B1:B22,A1:A22)
```

i.e.: Replace semicolons with commas.  Also, check that the cells contain numbers and not texts.